# "Authorization require" even though I specified Authorization

Tags: node.js, http, sendgrid, node-request, sendgrid-api-v3

In the following code, I specified Authorization with Bearer for OAuth2 for API. but I keep getting `401 - authorization required`. I have no idea why the auth doesn't work, I tried it on swagger, paw but everything did work but not on Node side.

```
let mailOpt = {
      uri: "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients",
      method: "POST",
      header: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${account.SENDGRID_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
      },
      body: "[\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            `    \"email\": \"${response[0].email}\"\n` +
            "  }\n" +
            "]"
}
```

when I print out the actual **mailOpt**, I get below. everything looks fine.

```
MAILopt { uri: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients',
  method: 'POST',
  header: 
   { Authorization: 'Bearer access_token' },
  body: '[\n  {\n    "email": "voqes@inboxbear.com"\n  }\n]' }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your options, you have the property `header` but it should be `headers`, that's why the `"Authorization"` part is being ignored.

Also, not sure if `uri` is a valid property, but `url` sure is.